# How to use echo in php array to return as a string

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to return an array of strings.  I do this:

```
$errors[] = toolbarCheckCreds($_COOKIE['uname'], $_COOKIE['pword'], $_COOKIE['rememberMe']);
    echo $errors[0];
```

and this in the function at the end:

```
return $errors;
```

and I set an error like this:

```
$errors[] = "error goes here!";
```

Basically, when I return my array, and echo it, it gives me the following output:

```
Array
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [PHP implode](http://www.tutorialarena.com/php/php-implode-function-array-to-string.php) to convert your Array to a string that you can echo. Using echo on an array will just display the data type.

```
return implode(' ', $errors);
```

If you want to separate the errors with a delimiter other than a space, just replace the space in the first parameter:

```
return implode(' :: ', $errors);
```

For example, if your errors array contained three values:

```
[ "Invalid data" , "404" , "Syntax error" ]
```

then your string, if you used the ::, would look like this when you run `echo` on the result:

```
Invalid data :: 404 :: Syntax error
```

See the reference link I included for another example.

Comment: how would I modify my current code to add something like you provided in the second example, with the "::"?

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop through your array. There are multiple ways of doing this, with my personal preference being using a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

For example, this will echo each error message in the array on a new line:

```
foreach ($errors as $error)
{
    echo "<br />Error: " . $error;
}
```

Comment: The advantage here is that your errors object is still an array. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
$list = array( 'one Thing', 'Two Things', 'The Things' );
echo implode( ", ", $list );
```

Result
One thing, two things, three things

Easy breezy, hope it helps i know i'm late but useful to someone else maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can't echo out an array's content as-is.

If you want to check the array's contents, you can use [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_export()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) with the `return` parameter set to `True`.