# Echo array with string as separator

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code in PHP, which searches a file for lines containing a string:

```
<?php
echo "Results for: ";
echo ($_POST['query']);
echo "<br><br>";
$file = 'completed.db';
$searchfor = ($_POST['query']);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

In the line, `echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);` in echos an array, separated by spaces.  If I wanted to separate the items by a different string, say `$entry = '<br>'`, how would you do it?

For example, if `$matches` was

- one
- two
- three

Then, the command should echo:

```
one<br>two<br>three<br>
```

Comment: implode("<br/>", $matches[0]);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use echo in php array to return as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051451/how-to-use-echo-in-php-array-to-return-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the break tag to the string

```
echo implode("\n<br>", $matches[0]);
```

And one more to trail since implode only goes between.

```
echo "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code simply uses implode with a different first argument, bu also adds the separator to the end (as per specification)

```
$entry = '<br>';
echo implode($entry, $matches[0]).$entry;
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!